# Using conditional statement with ArrayList.size()

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I tried using the if-else statement as a condition to add elements to an array list. However, it kept adding one more element above the condition.

```
private ArrayList<Musician> songMusicians;
this.songMusicians = new ArrayList<>();
Musician musician = new Musician(name);
if (songMusicians.size() < 6) { //same output for (songMusicians.size() <= 5)
    songMusicians.add(musician);
} else {
    System.out.println("You can't have more than 5 musicians per song");
}
```

So instead of adding 5 elements to the array list songMusicians, it added 6 elements.

Comment: @Deadpool This doesn't have to do with index; it's just an off-by-one error.

Comment: How come indexes and length are so confused!?!?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume there are 5 elements in the list and when you say `< 6`, it returns `true` and then you add one more which makes 6 elements in the list.

Just change it to `songMusicians.size() < 5`.

Answer (score 3):

songMusicians.size() < 5
use this in the if condition.

according to your code(i<6) the loop will run 6 times i.e. 0-1-2-3-4-5 and even if you do (i<=5) then still the loop will run 6 times i.e. 0-1-2-3-4-5. You should write (i<=4) or (i<5) for the loop to run 5 times i.e. 0-1-2-3-4 –